# Test and Training Data in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, sample-data

My DF is split into test and training sizes:

```
testSampleSize = 2573.0 
trainingSampleSize = 7719.0
```

I calculate the rows for the test sample, in using:

```
rows = random.sample(df.index, int(testSampleSize))
```

Where df is my dataframe.

To obtain test data I use:

```
df_test = bothDF.ix[rows]
```

However this df_test has a length of 2604, not the testSampleSize.

Now I drop these rows from the initial DF for the training data:

```
df_training = bothDF.drop(rows)
```

This df_training has a length of 7698.

Why do the lengths vary from the sample size created?

Comment: I'm guessing you have repeats in `rows = random.sample(df.index, int(testSampleSize))`. Look at `np.random.choice(df.index, int(testSampleSize), replace=False)`